# programatically open and login to control-m workload automation - java

Tags: java, control-m

i have to open and login control-m workload application from code. i tried opening the application by specifying the path in java. but i am unable to access the login text fields from code in order to enter credentials. is there any method or API available to perform the same?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Depends of your Control-M version:

versions 6 & 7:

```
start emgui -u user_name -p password -m server_name
```

Version 8:

```
start emwa.exe -u=user_name -p=password -s=server_name --nshost=IP_Server
```

Version 9.0.18

```
start emwa.exe -u=user_name -p=password -webhost=server_name -webport=18080
```